# how to arrange mn people for a photograph

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, problem-solving

A group of n families, each with m members, are to be lined up for a photograph. In how many ways can the nm people be arranged if members of a family must stay together?

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{equation*}
n!(m!)^n
\end{equation*}$$

Comment: The order of the members of each of the families matters, not just the first family.

Comment: Thanks.. fixed?

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Decide the order of the families.  Then for each individual family, choose the order of its members.